# How to pass a fiber optic through an aluminum laser enclosure?

Tags: experimental-physics, experimental-technique, laboratory-safety

This is a very technical question which I think is not typical on this site but it is for experimental physics so I'm trying it out because I can't find a better stack exchange

**Problem**

I'm trying to build a solid aluminum enclosure for a 10W laser with 80-20 frames, the enclosure has tubing/plumbing and fiber optics coming out of it.

**Question**

I want to get these out of the container in a way that is light tight and doesn't damage the plumbing or fiber optics. Are there commercially readily available components for passing through wire like objects while preventing direct line of sight to any laser light inside? Are there simple things that can be built to do this?

**Some Constraints**

Thank you for the useful comments! So one constraint is to not disconnect the fiber currently in use, or the pipes currently in use. Water leakage wouldn’t be pleasant and preventing any loss in the fiber from fiber fiber coupling wouldn’t be ideal. I’m inexperienced in the lab so I don’t know how much margin we have.

**Response**
I was thinking rubber grommets might not be completely light tight unless they’re snug on the fiber but even then I’d have to cut it to get it on the fiber. The other issue with that is I’d have to make the hole very close to the edge of the container. I guess these options will have to do though as a feedthrough risks losing light power. I suppose I’ll just add an extra container at the output port so there is no direct line of sight into the box.

Comment: Perhaps [rubber grommets](https://www.amazon.com/Grommets-Rubber-Industrial-Hardware/s?ie=UTF8&page=1&rh=n%3A16409771%2Cp_n_feature_seven_browse-bin%3A5485668011)?

Comment: Can you just break your fiber and put a bulkhead connector on the enclosure? If there's a reason not to do that (like very high power requirement) then google for a "fiber optic feedthrough". Most are connectorized but others are not. You may end up paying for a vacuum-tight solution you don't (say you) need.